# Layout gets adjusted when keyboard shows

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout I have an admob ad showing with an `EditText` in the layout. When I focus in the edit text to type something the keyboard appears and moves the admob ad over the edittext and you cant see what you are typing in.

this is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:isScrollContainer="false" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wood_floor" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <com.tyczj.bowling.adapters.RobotoThinTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="Add Bowler"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#33b5e5"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ab_solid_custom_blue_inverse_holo" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <com.tyczj.bowling.adapters.RobotoThinTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/line"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/bNameTV"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <com.tyczj.bowling.adapters.RobotoThinTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/line"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/lNameTV"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Right Handed" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/line"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:text="Left Handed" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/done"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/line"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:onClick="onDoneClick"
            android:text="@string/done" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="IAB_BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

in my manifest I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` in the activity but that didnt have any effect

How can I stop the ad from moving when the keyboard appears?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the mode adjustPan?  That may work better for you.  Since you have a RelativeLayout with an element aligned to the bottom of the screen, an adjustResize will always keep that element at the bottom of the screen.  You may be able to play with your layout to fix things by laying the ad out as being below the scrollview, rather than aligning to bottom.

Comment: if I add that in, the ad does not move but the scrollview does not scroll and it will need to when the keyboard appears or else you cant get to any of the other layout elements

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `LinearLayout` instead of outmost `RelativeLayout` and add the `ScrollView` with `android:layout_weight="1"` and the `AdView` with `android:layout_weight="0"`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    ...
    />
    ...
  </ScrollView>

  <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    .../>

</LinearLayout>
```